# Is it haram to miss Fajr if I have school that morning?

Tags: fajr

Asalamu Alaikum.

My name is Ryan and I am an Australian who wants to convert to Islam, but the only problem in the way is School. The problem I will have is will Allah forgive me for missing Fajr on a School morning?
Thank you brothers and sisters.

Comment: what time is it ? when you go to school ? I think you misunderstood something ... you can search it on google, like _salat time in australia_

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Haram means forbidden and is the wrong term in this context. Sinful is the right term.

Comment: The time for Fajr is from dawn to sunrise, it is unlikely that it clashes with your school. Praying is obligatory, you must find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Wa alaikum musalam

I'm a recent convert, and Islam has changed my lifestyle to the extent that I do my best to work my life around salah rather than the other way around. Once you realise that we're here to worship Allah, nothing else becomes more important and you're drawn to do this.

Fajr in particular is one of the most blessed salahs, in part because it is so difficult for many. There's an hadith that says:

The Messenger of Allah صلى الله عليه وسلم said: 'If the people knew what (reward) there is in the Isha prayer and Fajr prayer, they would come even if they had to crawl.'

So my suggestion is to do everything you can to find a way to read it (and all other salah) on time. If you try, with a sincere heart, Allah should make it easy for you to find a solution.

Please ask if you have any further questions about Islam. You are welcome to PM me if you like. May Allah bless you with iman.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it haram to miss Fajr if I have school that morning?**

Bismillah,

The word "haram" means "forbidden". Proper term to use would be "disobidience" from arabic **معصیت (Ma'siyat)**

Praying Salah at its specified time is Fard (obligation) based on following verse ([4:103](https://legacy.quran.com/4/103)):

> [image]
>
> *Sahih International*
>
> And when you have completed the prayer, remember Allah standing,
> sitting, or [lying] on your sides. But when you become secure,
> re-establish [regular] prayer. Indeed, **prayer has been decreed upon
> the believers a decree of specified times.**

So, one who misses Fajr without a good excuse is disobeying Allah, thus, committing a grave sin. Importance of Salah and seriousness of missing it canbe understood from the list of [major sins is Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_views_on_sin#Major_sins:_Al-Kabirah). You can take a look at [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_views_on_sin#Major_sins:_Al-Kabirah) on that:

> Some of the major or al-Kaba'ir sins in Islam:
>
> ```
> 1.Shirk (associating partners with Allah);
> 2.Committing murder (taking away someone's life);
> 3.Practicing sihr (sorcery);
> 4.Leaving off the five daily prayers (Salah);
> 5.Not paying the minimum amount of Zakat when the person is required to do so;
> 6.Not fasting on the days of Ramadan (without an excuse);
> 7.Not performing Hajj (while being able to do so);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

When you miss a salah for a valid reason you can make it up at a later time. Additionally, in the US fajr's adhan is at 3ish so you can pray it from 3 am to when the Suj rises. I hope that clarifies!

Comment: He said he's from Australia